# Why do I keep getting this error: "FATAL: password authentication failed for user "israelsanchez"?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am building a Spring Boot app that contains a PostgreSQL database. I've created an RDS of this database on AWS and am attempting to host my app via AWS Elastic Beanstalk. However after copying and pasting the RDS endpoint url into my applications.property, I receive the error mentioned in the question

Here is the code from my applications.property file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://letscook-db.cldqpbve1mun.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/
spring.datasource.username=israelsanchez
spring.datasource.password=<Mypassword>
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
server.error.include-messages=always
server.port=5000
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
```

Here is my pg_hba.conf file

```
# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------
#
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.

@authcomment@

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

@remove-line-for-nolocal@# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
@remove-line-for-nolocal@local   all             all                                     @authmethodlocal@
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
@remove-line-for-nolocal@local   replication     all                                     @authmethodlocal@
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            @authmethodhost@
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 @authmethodhost@
```

Here is my postgresql.conf file

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

#listen_addresses = '*'     # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
#port = 5432                # (change requires restart)
#max_connections = 100          # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directories = '/tmp'   # comma-separated list of directories
                    # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                    # (change requires restart)

# - TCP settings -
# see "man tcp" for details

#tcp_keepalives_idle = 0        # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_interval = 0        # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_count = 0       # TCP_KEEPCNT;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_user_timeout = 0           # TCP_USER_TIMEOUT, in milliseconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default

#client_connection_check_interval = 0   # time between checks for client
                    # disconnection while running queries;
                    # 0 for never

# - Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min      # 1s-600s
#password_encryption = scram-sha-256    # scram-sha-256 or md5
#db_user_namespace = off

# GSSAPI using Kerberos
#krb_server_keyfile = 'FILE:${sysconfdir}/krb5.keytab'
#krb_caseins_users = off 

# - SSL -

#ssl = off
#ssl_ca_file = ''
#ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
#ssl_crl_file = ''
#ssl_crl_dir = ''
#ssl_key_file = 'server.key'
#ssl_ciphers = 'HIGH:MEDIUM:+3DES:!aNULL' # allowed SSL ciphers
#ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = on
#ssl_ecdh_curve = 'prime256v1'
#ssl_min_protocol_version = 'TLSv1.2'
#ssl_max_protocol_version = ''
#ssl_dh_params_file = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command = ''
#ssl_passphrase_command_supports_reload = off
```

Comment: That is a template hba file. It is not the real file.

Comment: @jjanes how would I find the real file?

Comment: It should be named pg_hba.conf (not pg_hba.conf.sample) and in the same directory as postgresql.conf (but I suspect that *that* file is also the template file as normally the max_connections line is not commented out).  But also you have labelled this RDS, and surely you don't get access to either of these file when you use RDS, as in that case Amazon is in charge of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the times it is due to the configuration issues in pg_hba.conf file.

Here is how to configure:  https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/databases-postgresql